# List of tuples remove duplicates by first index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time with this one. I have a list of tuples but am only interested in removing duplicates based on the first item of the tuples.

I need to remove the duplicates from the individual lists by only looking at the first item in the tuple.

I need to compare the lists for duplicates where unique is in uniqueFound and only keep those from unique that are not in uniqueFound, also only interested in the first item of the tuple. The other numbers and values should not be considered. Here is what I came up with, and it's still passing N1 to the final list when it shouldn't. There has to be an easier way to do this?

```
#unique found
uniqueFound = [('N1', '20.3', 1, 58, 14),
         ('N2', '20.1', 1, 44, 14),
         ('N3', '21', 1, 23, 14),
         ('N1', '21', 1, 23, 14),
         ('N5', '33', 1, 34, 14)
         ]
unique = [('N0', '23', 2, 22, 1),
         ('N6', '33.1', 1, 25, 11),
         ('N3', '21', 1, 33, 12),
         ('N1', '44', 1, 2, 44),
         ('N7', '33.2', 4, 22, 12),
         ('N7', '3.2', 2, 21, 132)
         ]

#Remove duplicates
uniqueFound = dict((x[0], x) for x in uniqueFound).values()
unique = dict((x[0], x) for x in unique).values()

fmatches=[]
uniquefinal = []

for x in uniqueFound:
    for y in unique:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            fmatches.append(y)
        else:
            continue
fmatches = dict((x[0], x) for x in fmatches).values()
for x in unique:
    for y in fmatches:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            continue
        else:
            uniquefinal.append(x)
duplicatesrem = dict((x[0], x) for x in uniquefinal).values()
uniqueFinal = list(duplicatesrem)
print(uniqueFinal)
```

which yields

```
[('N0', '23', 2, 22, 1), ('N6', '33.1', 1, 25, 11), ('N3', '21', 1, 33, 12), ('N1', '44', 1, 2, 44), ('N7', '3.2', 2, 21, 132)]
```

What I'm going for (in unique but not in uniqueFound):

```
[('N0', '23', 2, 22, 1), ('N6', '33.1', 1, 25, 11), ('N7', '3.2', 2, 21, 132)]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Updated. I'm trying to remove the duplicates from each list itself based only on the first items of the tuple, and then compare them and keep the items in unique that are not in uniqueFinal also just based on the first items.

Comment: How you choose `N7` element? "by default" I would keep the first one..

Comment: It doesn't matter which one gets kept, just that 'N7' is kept in unique if it is not in uniqueFound, either one is okay. I'm only trying to look at the first index of the tuples and remove based only on that criteria.

Comment: Should it say "(in unique but not in *uniqueFound*:" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
uniqueFound = [('N1', '20.3', 1, 58, 14),
         ('N2', '20.1', 1, 44, 14),
         ('N3', '21', 1, 23, 14),
         ('N1', '21', 1, 23, 14),
         ('N5', '33', 1, 34, 14)
         ]
unique = [('N0', '23', 2, 22, 1),
         ('N6', '33.1', 1, 25, 11),
         ('N3', '21', 1, 33, 12),
         ('N1', '44', 1, 2, 44),
         ('N7', '33.2', 4, 22, 12),
         ('N7', '3.2', 2, 23, 1)
         ]

aux1 = set(e[0] for e in uniqueFound)
aux2 = set()
result = []
for e in unique:
    e0 = e[0]
    if e0 in aux1: continue
    if e0 in aux2: continue
    aux2.add(e0)
    result.append(e)
print(result)
```

`aux1` is an auxiliary set containing "keys" from `uniqueFound`.

`aux2` is an auxiliary set containing already used "keys"

if a "key" (`e0`) is found in `aux1` or `aux2`, do nothing. Otherwise add "key" to `aux2` and the element to the result

Comment: I selected this one as it handles the duplicates in each individual list too.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that utilizes dictionaries:

```
found = {i[0] for i in uniqueFound}
dct = {k: v for k, *v in unique if k not in found}
[(k, *v) for k, v in dct.items()]
# [('N0', '23', 2, 22, 1), ('N6', '33.1', 1, 25, 11), ('N7', '3.2', 2, 23, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop = {t[0] for t in uniqueFound} # set comprehension

# build a conditional list comprehension
uniqueFinal = [e for e in unique if e[0] not in drop]
```

Comment: Notice this gets more complicated if the task is to keep only one of the duplicated items fron a single list.

Comment: This one woun't remove duplicates from unique list.